# Does this locus have a name?

Tags: geometry, terminology, locus

This comes from variational analysis and in particular from the definition of the tangent cone of a set.

Say we have a circle centered at $(0, 1/\tau)$ with radius $1/\tau$, $\tau > 0$. All of these circles run through the origin. Take a point $(w, 0)$, $w \neq 0$ on the horizontal axis and let $(x_\tau, y_\tau)$ be the point where the line segment that connects $(w, 0)$ and $(0,1/\tau)$ intersects the circle.

[image: locus]

As $\tau$ moves on $(0, \infty)$ it forms the locus shown in the figure above (blue line). The points of the locus can be written in the parametric form

$$
\begin{align}
x(t) {}={}& \frac{tw}{\sqrt{w^2 + t^2}},\\
y(t) {}={}& t - \frac{t^2}{\sqrt{w^2 + t^2}},
\end{align}
$$

for $t\in (0,\infty)$. I wonder whether this locus has a name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parametric coordinates satisfy the Cartesian equation $$y^2 = \frac{x^2(w - x)}{ w + x}$$
which describes the ["right strophoid"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strophoid#The_right_strophoid). The full curve has reflective symmetry in the $x$-axis and includes asymptotic branches (with asymptote $x=-w$) corresponding to the locus of the "other" point of intersection of the line with the circle.

[image]

Image from Wikipedia. Attribution: Kmhkmh, [CC BY 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0), via Wikimedia Commons